# Unit testing with Jasmine Marbles does not cover code in Code Coverage report

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-coverage, jasmine-marbles

When I use Jasmine marbles for unit testing margeMap and switchMap, those specific blocks don't cover in code coverage report.

Is there a way to unit test margeMap and switchMap blocks so that they would be covered in code coverage report?

Comment: Please show us the snippet you want to test along with the current test implementation.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner sorry i dint understand what is snippet test

Comment: Snippet as in the piece of code that causes you problems.